# pandas plotting time serires

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Trying to plot YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS on the x-axis with values on the Y.

the 'df = xxxx' is

```
         tagName   tagValue            tagTimestamp
0   Oil Pressure  52.512268 2018-09-17 12:20:03.099
1   Oil Pressure  52.443478 2018-09-17 12:20:02.598
2   Oil Pressure  48.912914 2018-09-17 12:20:02.348
4   Oil Pressure  45.463978 2018-09-17 12:20:01.848
5   Oil Pressure  50.580151 2018-09-17 12:20:01.598
6   Oil Pressure  49.411255 2018-09-17 12:20:01.348
8   Oil Pressure  48.072506 2018-09-17 12:20:01.146
```

running `df.plot(kind='scatter',x='tagTimestamp', y='tagvalue', color='red')` returns the error `ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric` I would like to keep the entire date time in the x column.  I've reviewed all of the stack post closely related to this topic but have been unable to successfully convert this and plot it.

df.dtypes:

```
tagName                 object
tagValue               float64
tagTimestamp    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: The X-axis has missing values and is unevenly spaced. You can't convert it to a continuous-looking scale for obtaining a trend chart as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, is this what you are after?

```
import pandas as pd

data.dtypes
```

Gives:

```
tagValue               float64
tagTimestamp    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Here is the data:

```
tagValue            tagTimestamp
0  52.512268 2018-09-17 12:20:03.099
1  52.443478 2018-09-17 12:20:02.598
2  48.912914 2018-09-17 12:20:02.348
3  45.463978 2018-09-17 12:20:01.848
4  50.580151 2018-09-17 12:20:01.598
5  49.411255 2018-09-17 12:20:01.348
6  48.072506 2018-09-17 12:20:01.146
```

And then plotting as a line chart, rather than a scatter:

```
data.plot(x = 'tagTimestamp')
```

Gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use matplotlib's `scatter` instead.

```
plt.scatter(df["tagTimestamp"].values, df["tagValue"].values)
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

t = ["2018-09-17 12:20:03.099", "2018-09-17 12:20:02.598", "2018-09-17 12:20:02.348", "2018-09-17 12:20:01.848",
     "2018-09-17 12:20:01.598", "2018-09-17 12:20:01.348", "2018-09-17 12:20:01.146"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"time" : t, "value" : np.random.rand(len(t))})
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])

print(df.dtypes)   # time     datetime64[ns]
                   # value           float64
                   # dtype: object

plt.scatter(df["time"].values, df["value"], color="red")
```